# iOS how to combine multiple GPS coordinates into a single cluster on map based on zoom level?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, mapkit, zooming

I have a database with close to 5000 GPS coordinates that I want to show on a MapKit map. Due to the large number of pins, I want to combine pins that are close geographically into a single bubble/cluster and display a number of pins in that cluster.

As the user changes zoom level, the bubble breaks into smaller clusters of pins, until the user zooms close enough to see individual pins.

**How can I accomplish grouping map pins into clusters using MapKit?**

[image]

Comment: I know it's marked as duplicate but if you are looking for a fw use this https://github.com/litoarias/HACClusterMapViewController

Comment: @Vig Awesome, this is exactly what I needed for a prototype :)